# Evaluating $\int (\tan^3x+\tan^4x) dx $ using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

solving $$\int (\tan^3x+\tan^4x) dx $$ using substitution $$t = \tan x$$

My approach has led me to $ \int (1+t)t\sin^2xdt$ which has an $x$ too much and isn't easily solvable for me. If I remove the $x$ I get $\sin^2(\arctan(t))$ and that's not too nice to work with...

Comment: If $t = \tan x$, what becomes $dx$ in terms of $dt$ and $t$?

Comment: $dx = \cos^2x dt = \cos^2(\arctan(t))dt$ (but I've kept $\cos^2x$ and divide it with $\cos^2x$ from a $\tan x$ so that I've $\sin^2x$ left.

Comment: You are possibly misusing the word _solving_. In math, that term usually means that there is some equation involving an unknown of some kind, and you have deduce what the unknown is. There is a tendency to misuse the term _solving_ as to mean "finding the answer to a math question", but that's not how mathematicians use it. Here, it might be better to say that you are _integrating_, _evaluating the integral_, or _simplifying_.

Comment: Not the optimal way, but okay. Now, can you simplify $\cos^2 (\arctan t)$?

Comment: Have you tried the universal substitution. Maybe they would help but not sure, try it only if you have the nerfs to :D

Comment: $\tan^3(x)=\tan(x)(\tan^2(x))=\tan(x)\sec^2(x)-\tan(x)$ gives you the first term, assuming you know the antiderivative for $\tan(x)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm sure it's possible to simplify it. But I don't know how.

Comment: @randomname What's the "universal substitution"? If you mean $t=tan(x/2)$ so yes. And the calculations isn't nice. And the specifications for the exercise it to use$ t=tanx $

Comment: @iveqy Big hint: $\tan' x = 1 + \tan^2 x$. (Another big hint would be the obvious equation $x = \arctan t$)

Comment: @DanielFischer is $tan'x$ the derivate of $tan x$? I'm sorry but I don't get your hints.

Comment: Yes, $\tan' x$ is the derivative of $\tan$, evaluated in $x$.

Comment: Hint: Our function is $(\tan x+\tan^2 x)(\sec^2 x-1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas unfortunately $sec$ is not used in my country and hence I should learn to solve this without it. (even if I'm of course open to learn about $sec$ too).

Comment: Well, the function $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ presumably has a name, just not $\sec x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unfortunately $\sec$ is not used in my country

If you feel unconfortable with $\sec $ you may proceed from your last integral

\begin{equation*}
I=\int (1+t)t\sin ^{2}\left( \arctan t\right) \,dt
\end{equation*}

by using the following trigonometric identity

\begin{equation*}
\sin ^{2}x=\frac{\tan ^{2}x}{1+\tan ^{2}x},\qquad x=\arctan t,
\end{equation*}

which you can derive from the fundamental identity $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$ to obtain

\begin{equation*}
\sin ^{2}\left( \arctan t\right) =\frac{t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}.
\end{equation*}

Consequently

\begin{equation*}
I=\int (1+t)t\frac{t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\,dt=\int \frac{t^{3}+t^{4}}{1+t^{2}}\,dt,
\end{equation*}

which is integrable by partial fractions. By long division we compute

\begin{equation*}
\frac{t^{4}+t^{3}}{1+t^{2}}=t^{2}+t-1+\frac{-t+1}{1+t^{2}}.
\end{equation*}

So

\begin{equation*}
I=\int \left( t^{2}+t-1\right) dt+\int \frac{-t+1}{1+t^{2}}dt.
\end{equation*}

Since

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{-t+1}{1+t^{2}}dt &=&-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}dt+\int 
\frac{1}{1+t^{2}}dt \\
&=&-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( 1+t^{2}\right) +\arctan t+C,
\end{eqnarray*}

we thus have

\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\frac{1}{3}t^{3}+\frac{1}{2}t^{2}-t-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(
1+t^{2}\right) +\arctan t+C \\
&=&\frac{1}{3}\tan ^{3}x+\frac{1}{2}\tan ^{2}x-\tan x-\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(
1+\tan ^{2}x\right) +x+C.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

Let's wrap it up. Let $t = tanx$, so $dt = sec^2xdx = (1 + tan^2x)dx = (1 + t^2)dx$, and $dx = \dfrac{dt}{1 + t^2}$. So $I = \int\dfrac{t^3 + t^4}{1 + t^2} dt = \int \left(t - \dfrac{t}{1 + t^2} + t^2 - 1 + \dfrac{1}{1 + t^2}\right)dt = \dfrac{t^3}{3} + \dfrac{t^2}{2} - t - \dfrac{ln(1 + t^2)}{2} + tan^{-1}t + C = \dfrac{tan^3x}{3} + \dfrac{tan^2x}{2} - tanx - ln|secx| + x + C$

Answer (score 0):

Solve separately:
first: $\int \tan^3x dx$:
$$\int \tan^3x dx=\int \tan^2 x (\tan x dx)=\int (\sec^2 x-1)\tan x dx= $$
$$=\int \sec^2x \tan x dx -\int \tan xdx=\int (\sec x)^1( \sec x\tan x dx)+\int \frac{-\sin x dx}{\cos x}=$$
$$=\frac{\sec^2 x}{2}+\ln |\cos x| +c. $$

Second: $\int \tan^4 x dx$:
$$\int \tan^4 x dx=\int (\sec^2x-1)^2dx=\int (\sec^4 x-2\sec^2x +1)dx=  $$
$$=\int \sec^4 x dx -2\int \sec^2 x dx+\int dx = $$
$$=\int (1+\tan^2x)\sec^2x dx -2\int \sec^2x +x+c= $$
$$=\int \sec^2x dx+\int \tan^2x \sec^2 x dx -2\int \sec^2 xdx +x+c= $$
$$\int (\tan x)^2 \sec^2x dx -\int \sec^2 x dx+x+c =$$
$$=\frac{\tan^3 x}{3}-\tan x+x+c. $$

The, the answer is
$$\int(\tan^2x+\tan^4x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2x+\ln|\cos x|+\frac{1}{3}\tan^3x -\tan x+x+c.$$

Note: is easy to see that my solution and the LAcarguy above differ only a constant.